# how can I loop url arrays in a page after the autoscroll hits the bottom part of the page?

Tags: javascript, loops, autoscroll

```
<body>
<div id="scr" style="overflow:auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
    <p id="content"></p>
</div>
```

var sites = ['linkexample.com', 'http://link2.com', 'http://link3.com'];

```
 i = 3;
 ctr = 0;
 while(ctr < i){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="100%" data="' + sites[ctr] + '"></object>';

function ScrollDiv(){
   if(document.getElementById('scr').scrollTop<(document.getElementById('scr').scrollHeight-document.getElementById('scr').offsetHeight)){-1
         document.getElementById('scr').scrollTop=document.getElementById('scr').scrollTop+1
         }

   else {
         ctr++;
        }
```

setInterval(ScrollDiv, 5)
    }

};

Comment: are you able to find if autoscroll has reached the bottom of page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code example iterates through the array and loads the url into `<p id="content"></p>`

Also I have corrected some mistakes in your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>
<body>
            <div id="scr" style="overflow:auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
                <p id="content"></p>

            </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ctr = 0;

var sites = ['http://link1.com', 'http://link2.com', 'http://link3.com'];  
function ScrollDiv(){
    if(document.getElementById('scr').scrollTop<(document.getElementById('scr').scrollHeight-document.getElementById('scr').offsetHeight)){
        document.getElementById('scr').scrollTop=document.getElementById('scr').scrollTop+1;
    }else{
        ctr++;
        if(ctr>2){
            ctr=0;
        }
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object width="100%" height="100%" data="' + sites[ctr] + '"></object>';
    }
}

setInterval(ScrollDiv, 3000);

</script>
</html>
```

There is no page content in the example that you have provided. I am unclear about what you want to do with scrolls.

Comment: thanks this is a big help :D.. its for page monitoring stuff. sorry im just a newbie here